# Select only the innermost div with specific text

Tags: jquery

I need to select only the innermost div tag that contains specific text when the number of nested div tags is not known.

Given:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>Some Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The selector should only contain the innermost div tag (and text). Using $("div:contains('Some Text')") returns all three divs since they all contain the text.

Comment: Maybe something like: `$('div:not(:has(div))');`?

Comment: Do you want to select the element by text or only by "level"? It's not clear from your description.

Comment: @Joe - doesn't work since I need to specify the text.

Comment: @markm247: Just add `:contains('Some Text')`.

Comment: @FelixKling - I mentioned that I wanted to select div that contains text but I've edited the question for clarity.

Comment: I'm inclined to close the question as duplicate of [jQuery selector for an element that directly contains text?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7896455/218196), because that seems what you really want to do.

Comment: @FelixKling - It is the same issue. Answer below is a better one than the question you mentioned. Not sure how that is handled on Stack Overflow. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:contains()` to find a div that contains your text, and then filter with `:not(:has(div))`:

```
$('div:contains(Some Text):not(:has(div))')
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/8eGLJ/1/

Comment: i did the same but found that is better to add another ':contains(Some Text)' inside

Comment: `$('div:contains(Some Text):last')` would also work.