# Finding the DOM element with specific text in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I know how to find specific text, but I'm really struggling to find elements with specific text 
for example: `<span class="foo">Special</span>`

Is there example like this script below to find elemements with text?

```
var txt = window.document.body.innerHTML;
if (txt.match(/Special/)) {
    // do something if true
    alert("Found");
} else {
    // do something if false
    alert("Sorry");

};
```

Comment: jQuery? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896455/jquery-selector-for-an-element-that-directly-contains-text

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? [Don't use regex to parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @mplungjan Question has no jQuery tag.

Comment: @Kinduser - hence my question and not hammer closing - new SO user  could still want a solution that involved jQuery without tagging it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could e.g. catch every element inside your document and check if any of them contains given text.

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("*"),
    res = Array.from(elems).find(v => v.textContent == 'Special');
    
    console.log(res ? 'found!' : 'not found');
```

```html
<span class="foo">Special</span>
<span class="foo">Else</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure Javascript just grab element's parent like this:

```
var x = this.parentElement.nodeName; //x=="span"
```

or

```
var x = this.parentElement; //x == <span> object
```

With jQuery just grab element's parent like this:

```
$(this).parents("span");
```

So if you add above line inside your if you can get span element as object or as text.