# Get div element based on text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below. I want to retrieve the element that contains the text below. I don't know which div the text is in, so the whole page has to be searched.

```
$('*', 'body')
        .addBack()
        .contents()
        .filter(function(){
            return this.nodeType === 3;
        })
        .filter(function(){
            // Text below: {launch=[MODULE]}
            return this.nodeValue.indexOf('{launch=[MODULE]}') != -1;
        })
        .each(function(){
          // How do I receive the element here?
          console.log(this);
        });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the purpose of `$('*')`?

Comment: To select all nodes at once I guess.

Comment: Why do you need to select every element?

Comment: Because I don't know in which element on the page the text is in it. I'm trying to get the element that contains the text.

Comment: Ok I see that. Does `this.nodeValue` not work inside `each`?

Comment: Well, I've tried it but I get the text inside the console.

Comment: That's because you're using `console.log`. What are you looking to do with the text?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229362/discussion-between-jasper-and-evolutionxbox).

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29418265/924299) helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery selector for an element that directly contains text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896455/jquery-selector-for-an-element-that-directly-contains-text)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can collect all the `<div>` elements and then loop through them, checking the `textContent` property, each time.

**Example:**

```
// GRAB ALL THE DIVS
const allDivs = [...document.getElementsByTagName('div')];

// SET THE SEARCH PHRASE
const searchPhrase = '{launch=[MODULE]}';

// LOOP THROUGH ALL THE DIVS, LOOKING FOR THE SEARCH PHRASE
for (let div of allDivs) {

  if (div.textContent !== searchPhrase) continue;

  console.log(div);
}
```

Comment: @Scratte - we're good. I've just come back in from having a coffee and enjoying the spring sunshine outside and I came back and noticed the new question.

Comment: Ok :) I noticed you noticed, since I saw your comment on it. Anyway, I understand where you're coming from. Good luck :)

Comment: @Scratte - Bookmarklet: `javascript:(()=>{[...document.querySelectorAll('[href^="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/"]')].forEach((link)=>{link.remove()})})();`