# Can I add a class to an element if a matching class exists?

Tags: jquery

The issue to solve is to inactivate the months that are not in the list. I have a list of posts that populates the DOM and an unordered list aside. I only want the user to see the months highlighted where there is a matching HTML row.

Here is what my html looks like:

```
<div data-filter="February">Feb</div>
<div data-filter="April">Apr</div>
```

Here is my unordered list:

```
<ul>
  <li>January</li>
  <li>February</li>
  <li>March</li>
  <li>April</li>
  <li>May</li>
  <li>June</li>
  <li>July</li>
  <li>August</li>
  <li>September</li>
  <li>October</li>
  <li>November</li>
  <li>December</li>  
</ul>
```

Can someone please show me the logic to only highlight the months of February and April?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

- Use nested loops to iterate over the elements.
- Take the substring of the first 3 characters for list elements, and set `font-weight` property to bold if the substring matches the div text content.

**Check following code:**

```js
const filterElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-filter]');
const listElements = document.querySelectorAll('li');

listElements.forEach(function(listElement) {

  filterElements.forEach(function(filterElement) {
    var el = listElement.textContent.substring(0, 3);

    if (el === filterElement.textContent) {
      listElement.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>January</li>
  <li>February</li>
  <li>March</li>
  <li>April</li>
  <li>May</li>
  <li>June</li>
  <li>July</li>
  <li>August</li>
  <li>September</li>
  <li>October</li>
  <li>November</li>
  <li>December</li>
</ul>
<div data-filter="February">Feb</div>
<div data-filter="April">Apr</div>
```

Comment: That's beautiful, thank you! That's so cool, I need to learn JavaScript! This is way better than JQuery in my opinion. It just looks like a readable language. Thanks again!!

Comment: That logic is great. Thank you for going through that.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `forEach` you can use the jquery `:contains` which is more faster.

jQuery version:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".filter").each(function(index,element){
        $(".list li:contains("+ $(element).data("filter") +")").css("font-weight","bold");
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".filter").each(function(index,element){
    $(".list li:contains("+ $(element).data("filter") +")").css("font-weight","bold");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-filter="February" class="filter">Feb</div>
<div data-filter="April" class="filter">Apr</div>

<ul class="list">
  <li>January</li>
  <li>February</li>
  <li>March</li>
  <li>April</li>
  <li>May</li>
  <li>June</li>
  <li>July</li>
  <li>August</li>
  <li>September</li>
  <li>October</li>
  <li>November</li>
  <li>December</li>  
</ul>
```

Reference: [jQuery selector for an element that directly contains text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896455/jquery-selector-for-an-element-that-directly-contains-text)